# Send response from action method liferay

Tags: ajax, servlets, liferay, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I have an actionURL in my jsp from which I am calling a method called "updateDB" in my java file. 
whenever I submit the form through an AJAX request using A.io.request , this udpateDB function in my java code is being called, where I am doing some database CRUD operations.

I want to know how can I send some values(either success/failure  status of database insertion) back to my jsp from java code to the success callback of my A.io.request ajax call.

You can find below my Ajax request :

```
Liferay.provide(window,‘submitForm’,
function() {
var A = AUI();
A.io.request(‘${”formsubmissionURL”}’,{
method: ‘POST’,
form: { id: ‘<portlet:namespace />fm’ },
on: {
success: function(){
alert(form submitted”);

// I WANT DATABASE SUCCESS OR FAILURE STATUS HERE FROM JAVA CODE
     }
   }
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data values by writing it to resourceResponse.

`response.getWriter().write(String/int/char[])`

Here, response can be servletResponse or portletResponse(resourceResponse)

You can get data in javascript like

`this.get('responseData')` inside success method.

EDIT:
As you are calling action method via ajax call, below code may be helpful.

`PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(actionResponse)`

Get httpServletResponse from code above and then you can use `response.getWriter().write` method.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But I am calling my action method in java. Can i use resourceResponse in that action method ?

Comment: I believe ResourceResponse  can be used in serveResource method . Pls correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Edited answer, you may use whatsoever response type you have.

Comment: Hi Pankaj. thanks again.

The liferay action method has (ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) as parameters. It doesn't provide any methods to get the writer and write my string/array to the jsp

Comment: Well, ideally you should use resource-url for ajax call,which will call serveResource method of controller.

Comment: The problem is I am submitting the form data in AJAX post. Can form values be retrieved in serveResource mehtod ?

Comment: Thanks I changed it to resourceurl with Ajax post